# Logstash http filter with array fields in body

Tags: http, logstash

I want to create an HTTP Logstash filter that invokes an API using a request body that includes an array field. The input plugin reads a document as follows:

```
{
"tags": ["foo", "bar"]
}
```

and i want to pass tags fields to the http filter. My http filter configuration is:

```
    http {
            url => "${TAG_GENERATOR_URL}"
            body =>  {
                "previous_tags" => "%{tags}"
            }
            verb => POST
            body_format => "json"
            ecs_compatibility => "disabled"
            target_body => tmp
            add_field => {
                "tag.version" => "${TAG_LATEST_VERSION}"
                "new_tags" => "%{[tmp][tags]}"
            }
        }
```

But unfortunately the tags field is serialized and transmitted as a string. Is there a way to send this tags field as an array instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing this file

**{path where logstash is installed}/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.6.0/gems/logstash-filter-http-1.4.3/lib/logstash/filters/http.rb**

Find the **def filter(event)** function.

```
def filter(event)
    url_for_event = event.sprintf(@url)
    headers_sprintfed = sprintf_object(event, @headers)
    if !headers_sprintfed.key?('content-type') && !headers_sprintfed.key?('Content-Type')
        headers_sprintfed['content-type'] = @body_format == "json" ? "application/json" : "text/plain"
    end
    query_sprintfed = sprintf_object(event, @query)
    body_sprintfed = sprintf_object(event, @body)
    # we don't need to serialize strings and numbers
    if @body_format == "json" && body_sprintfed.kind_of?(Enumerable)
        body_sprintfed = LogStash::Json.dump(body_sprintfed)
    end


    # add this
    puts body_sprintfed       # output the original text to the console
    puts body_sprintfed.class # Maybe Hash

    tags = event.get("tags")
    body_sprintfed = { :previous_tags => JSON.parse(tags) }
    puts tags                # check your tags value
    puts body_sprintfed      # check the changed value
    #


    options = { :headers => headers_sprintfed, :query => query_sprintfed, :body => body_sprintfed }
```

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-http